# How do I iterate over the routes in a playframework 2 scala application?

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0

What is the equivalent for play.mvc.Router.routes in playframework 2 scala?

In playframework 1.x I could Iterate over the available routes in the controller:

```
for(Route route:Router.routes){
    ...
}
```

How would I do this with playframework 2 scala?

The not found [dev mode template](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages/devNotFound.scala.html) seems to be able to iterate over them but I need to do this in a controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can’t really do that with Play 2.0.

Routes are defined as a `PartialFunction[RequestHeader, Handler]`, there is no way to know the domain of this function.

Nevertheless, as shown in the *not found* template, you can retrieve some information on the application’s routes: the Play 2.0 router generates a `documentation` field returning, for each route of the application, its HTTP method (`GET`, `PUT`, etc.), its path pattern and finally the call as it was written in the `conf/routes` file.

The router generates a `Routes` object which is loaded by your Play application when started, you can access it as follows:

```scala
for {
  routes <- play.api.Play.current.routes.toList
  (method, pattern, call) <- routes.documentation
} yield {
  …
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to get more info using reflection? In fact I would like to generate documentation for my api.

Comment: And the above example does not seem to be working -> not found: value Routes. Do I need some import?

Comment: Indeed, the `Routes` object is loaded at runtime, so it’s not visible in your classpath at compile time. I edited the code snippet, let me know if it doesn’t work.

Comment: type mismatch;  found   : Seq[Unit]  required: Option[?] - I fear my Scala skills are not there yet to fix this myself